# Netlogo extrawidget extensions numeric input widget malfunctions intermittently

Tags: netlogo

I am currently using the extrawidget extension in Netlogo as a frontend GUI and using it as a parent model in Levelspace to call and push information to a child model. I use ls:assign to push the information from the parent (extrawidgrt GUI) global variables to the child global variables. All the widgets works fine except the numeric input widget. I have 30 separate numeric input widgets. Sometimes all the numeric inputs work properly but sometimes (and often) either the number input is not received by the child model or the number input won't clear in the extrawidget's GUI when using a programmed "clear-input" button (The "clear input button" has all the proper  "xw:ask" and "[ xw:set-value 0]" in place for all the numeric input widgets).

When this happens it happens with different numeric widgets each time, sometimes 2 numeric widgets at a time.

Like I said, sometimes everything works fine but sometimes this malfunction happens.

Any insights to what might be causing this?

Thanks

Rudy

Comment: Since it happens reasonably often, would it be possible to try different random seeds? When you find one that leads to the error, you could send the model with the appropriate random seed (so it's reproducible) as a bug report.

Comment: Thank you JenB, I'll try that.